# GET request returns html in Node and Express App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have created an app using Node with Express. when ever i make a get request it return the html file that im rendering from the node server.
I have rendered the html file using a route.And it keep on sending the html file for every get request.

The code of node app

```
import express from 'express';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import passport from 'passport';
import cros from 'cors';
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import webpackmiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware';
import webpackHotMiddleware from 'webpack-hot-middleware';
import webpackConfig from '../webpack.config.dev';
import regusers from './models/regusers.model';
import Router from './routes/UserRouter';

const cross = cros();
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const port =3000;
const compile=webpack(webpackConfig);
const db='mongodb://localhost/parkspace';

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

mongoose.connect(db);

app.use(webpackmiddleware(compile,{
  hot:true,
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  noInfo:true
}));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compile));
app.use(cross);
app.use(router);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
   extended:true
}));

app.get('/*',(req,res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./index.html'));
});

Router(app);

app.listen(port,()=> console.log('Running on port: '+port));
```

My Router file

```
import Authentication from '../auth/auth';
import passportService from '../services/passport';
import passport from 'passport';

const requireAuth = passport.authenticate('jwt',{session:false});

const user = (app) => {

    app.get('/',requireAuth,function (req,res){
        res.send({hi:'there'});
    });

    app.post('/signup',Authentication.signup);
}

export default user;
```

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put `Router(app);` before your rendering `index.html` logic:

```
Router(app);

app.get('/*',(req,res) => {
   res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,'./index.html'));
});
```

But your path for XHR get request in `Router.js` should be more specific, like `/auth`. You could also check `req.xhr` to distinguish if a request is from XHR or just a rendering request.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because in your route you have a wildcard `/*`, so no matter where you go, the html file will be sent.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes i know that but how to avoid getting html file when making get request? i need to server the html file like this since im using react which is a single page application and defining separate routes to serve html files wont help.

Comment: I don't have experience with React, but I guess this is not the way to accomplish what you want. In a SPA you don't keep rendering/sending the index file every time, but just its content.
Maybe you should post this as a React topic. You will get better help!