# How to call node.js server javascript from html page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web

### Situation

I have a html page which calls multiple javascript files. Everything works on client-side right now.

Because I need to execute a jar within javascript, I am switching to Node.js. (applets are deprecated)

However, I am new to node.js and confused about how to link everything.

---

### I have :

**index.html** which calls various .js scripts (files.js,objects.js,etc.)

**webServer.js** which makes the node.js server

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    fs.readFile('index.html', function(err, data) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write(data);
    res.end();
    });

}).listen(8080);
```

**javaApp.js** which executes a jar

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var child = exec('java -jar E:/JavaApp.jar',
function (error, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('Output -> ' + stdout);
    if(error !== null){
        console.log("Error -> "+error);
    }
});
module.exports = child;
```

---

### The question

I would like, when clicking on a button in my html, to call javaApp.js on the server side.

I know Express can be used to link index.html to webServer.js, but I don't understand how to link index.html to the code used by the server.

i.e. **How can I call javaApp.js from index.html if there's no function name in it?**

Is this answer relevant ? [How to call node.js server side method from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14951251/how-to-call-node-js-server-side-method-from-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to call the jar on the server you have to create a route for it(maybe using express).

```
router.get('/call-java-app', function (req, res, next){
//call you function in here
//respond with any data you want
res.send('Your data here');
});
```

Your button would have to make a get request at `/call-java-app` and optionally wait for any response from the server.

```
var url = '/call-java-app';
console.log(url);
var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) {
        //handle server response here if you want to
    }
}
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true); // false for synchronous request
xmlHttp.send(null);
```

Comment: Note : Have to be careful of the way the index.html is routed else the response is the whole html page (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41334892/get-request-returns-html-in-node-and-express-app)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I call javaApp.js from index.html if there's no function name in it?

You can't. At least not sensibly.

Change it so it exports a function you can call if you want to call it multiple times.

Since it is asynchronous, you should make that function return a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

In your webserver, [require](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/requiring-modules-in-node-js-everything-you-need-to-know-e7fbd119be8?gi=576d152408ce) the [module](https://www.nodebeginner.org/blog/post/nodejs-tutorial-what-are-node.js-modules/) you write to get access to the function it exports.

Write a [route](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html) which calls that function and returns a suitable HTTP response.

Then cause the browser to make an HTTP request to that route by clicking a [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a), submitting a [form](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms), using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), or whatever other method you like.

Answer (score 1):

Your webserver is now as simple as it (almost) can be. Just sending index.html when the ip+port 8080 is called with http (get). 
Before you can use your jar-module you have to make a requiere in your webserver:

```
var child = require('javaApp')
```

This will give you access to "child" wrappet with a error-function. What "child" actual is doing and can do, you probably know (i hope). If you skip the index.html you can send some response from your "child" to see how it works.